# write a part of a file to another file

Tags: python

I want to read a input file (input.txt) line by line in a main directory. This input file consists of the name of some subfolders (subfolder1, subfolder2,...). Each subfolder contains a file (for instance the subfolder1 contains subfolder1.pdb) with the same name. The code will read each subfolder's name from the input.txt and enter into each subfolder. Then it will write into a new file (e.g. subfolder1.txt) a specific part (the part between the "file name" line and "abc" line) of a file (e.g. subfolder1.pdb) in each subfolder (e.g. subfolder1). How can I do that?

The content of the file (subfolder1.pdb) in subfolder1 is here:

**subfolder1.pdb**

```
subfolder1.pdb
12
xy
...
abc
kl
...
```

The content of desired output file (**subfolder1.txt**) for subfolder1.pdb:

```
subfolder1.pdb
12
xy
...
abc
```

The content of the file (subfolder2.pdb) in subfolder2 is here:

**subfolder2.pdb**

```
subfolder2.pdb
54
mn
...
abc
xy
...
```

The content of desired output file (**subfolder2.txt**) for subfolder1.pdb:

```
subfolder2.pdb
54
mn
...
abc
```

The code I try to use is below. I don't know how to complete it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        os.chdir(line.strip())

        #do something

        os.chdir('..')
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you'll be reading from a different file than the one you'll be writing to, you're going to have to have multiple files open. If these are always the same files, you only need to do two `open`s. For example, the following just copies every line to the other file:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as inp_f:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as out_f:
        for line in inp_f:
            out_f.write(line)
```

If you need to make the output file depend on what is in each line of the input file, you can either first open all possible output files, and then loop through the input file, writing to whichever file you need, or you can only open each output file as needed. For example:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as inp_f:
    for line in inp_f:
        output_file_path = some_function(line)
        with open(output_file_path, "a") as out_f:
            out_f.write(line)
```

(Note that I'm opening the output file in `a`ppend mode, to make sure it's not continuously over-written. Also note that, if the input file is large, this will do a lot of opening and closing files, which may be slow.)

Comment: 1) How can I select a specific part of file? 2) Ouputfile name should be the same with its subfolder. In your code it is not so.

Comment: 1) You can select only part of the file by putting a condition before the `write` call. 2) That's trivial to fix: I made the output file path the result of a function call. You're free to have that function return whatever path name you want.